# Should I parseInt response.status code just making sure it is number format in my async public npm package?

Tags: javascript

I'm building an NPM package, normally, if the user makes a request, the server will respond with status code.

I know everybody makes the status code ***number*** format.

But is it possible, for example, PHP can return string format of status code?

So my question becomes:

1. Can backend return you a string format of `response.status`?
2. If they can, should I `parseInt` that status code in my NPM package to make sure everybody's code won't break? Or should I just throw an error?

Comment: That really depends on how you expect your npm package to be used. Some argue that you want "strict input and strict output" while others argue that you should accept "relaxed input" while still providing "strict output". Depending on your browser's expectations you should also consider that ```parseInt``` used to consider strings with numbers starting with 0 to be octal. While this has changed, if you plan to support old browsers you may want to specify the base.

Comment: Are you referring to the HTTP status code, or to some arbitrary `status` field in your response body?

Comment: I mean the fetch api
When I call `fetch(api).then(res => { //this res.status })`